# mysql insert with java and php: no error but no insert

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, insert

I have an Android java method that calls a remote php to insert data into a mysql table.

This is **java code** client side:

```
public static void insert(String email1, String email2) {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email1", email1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email2", email2));

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myserver:8080/insert.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //How to catch and print php echo() here??
}
```

and this is the **insert.php** server side (*re-edited*):

```
<?php   
    $mysqli_connection = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "password", "mydb");
    if ($mysqli_connection->connect_errno) {
        echo ("Connection Failure");
        exit();
    }


    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if ($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `mytable` (`email1`, `email2`) VALUES (?,?)")) {
        echo 'Success';
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_GET['email1'], $_GET['email2']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Error Inserting Content';
    }

    $mysqli->close();   
?>
```

When I call my java insert() method, **no exception is returned, but no insert is done** and mytable is empty.

- 1) What is wrong?
- 2) How can I see which error occured? How can I see a "log" of the the php-side execution?

Thank you very much.
Geltry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your `HttpResponse/HttpEntity`. There you should see either 'Success' or 'Error Inserting Content'. You can also add the concrete `errno` and `error` string in your response to see, what's really going wrong.

You also mix HTTP POST and HTTP GET in your request. On the client side you use a HttpPost object and on the server side you expect the _GET variables to be set. You must use either GET or POST on *both* sides. Otherwise client and server won't understand each other.

With [HttpEntity.getContent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29) you can read from an `InputStream`. Another approach would be to use [EntityUtils.toString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) to get a string representation of the response's content.

Comment: I read HttpResponse/HttpEntity with no success. Can you please tell me exaclty how? For instance: httpEntity.getMessage() or similar... Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with no success? See also the modified answer.

Comment: Your suggestion was right (and I had no mysqli library in php.ini)

Answer (score 3):

use `backtick` instead of single quote for column names and/or tableNames

```
INSERT INTO mytable(`email1`,`email2`) VALUES('$email1','$email2')
```

when do you use backtick?

- when column name or table name is a [Reserved Keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)
- when it contains space,

eg,

```
CREATE TABLE `hello word`(`Record ID` INT,....)
```

and you query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please take time to read the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Now I'm using backtick (and when I'll risolve, I'll also resolve the injection problem...). But it insert no data in my table. I don't know how to read errors adn messages printed in the 'echo' php function. I can't obtaind them reading HttpResponse/HttpEntity. :(